# What's the difference between "ĉiu" and "ĉiuj"?

Tags: word-usage, correlatives

Somehow I can't wrap my head around *ĉiu* and *ĉiuj*?
Isn't *ĉiu* already 'everyone'? Why do I need (or only sometimes) the *j*-finaĵo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/oa-vortecaj_vortetoj/tabelvortoj_u.html#i-our):

- *Oni uzas ĉiu, se oni konsideras la individuojn aparte.*
- *Oni uzas ĉiuj, se oni pensas pri la tuta grupo kune.*

I.e. *ĉiu* corresponds (for the most part) to "each" and *ĉiuj* to "all". Examples:

- *Al ĉiu el la infanoj mi donis po tri pomoj* -> I gave each of my children three apples (each individual ended up with three of their own)
- *El ĉiuj miaj infanoj Ernesto estas la plej juna* -> Out of [the group of] all my children, Ernesto is the youngest.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, *ĉiu* is singular and *ĉiuj* is plural. Therefore, *ĉiu* refers to one thing at a time, and *ĉiuj* refers to many things (collectively.)

You can also check how these are glossed in a bilingual dictionary.

- ĉiu: each, chacun, jede
- ĉiuj: all, tous, alle